# Set image as first element in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to set image as first element in spinner without any text and then other options as text. I have googled a lot but didn't get anything. What I am getting is either image and text with all options or text only.

Comment: Are you using Custom Adapter?

Comment: You can also use a customized popup menu to look like a spinner with a button

Comment: @Apoorv-I have also tried it but it doesn't solve my problem. Using custom I am getting images in all options.

Comment: @IllegalArgument- Thanks for ur suggestion.I got my work done using customized popup menu.